# Single library for Android and iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, portable-class-library

I'm new to Xamarin and have developed Xamarin `Class Library` for iOS and Android separately. The library has some business logic that launches a `ViewController` for iOS and `Activity` for Android. The generated binary for iOS and Android is iOS.dll and Android.dll respectively. These libraries are then consumed in Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android native apps.

There are some points in the business logic that are same for Android and iOS. Is there a way to develop a single library that has the entire business logic with conditional checks for both the platforms for different logics.

I looked into Portable Class Library, but it asks to include Xamarin.Forms for using it. I'm not using Xamarin.Forms in any part of the app. I get the below error when I use the library

**PCL Code**

```
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
{
    Lib_iOS.Helper helper = new Lib_iOS.Helper();
    helper.launchScreen(parameters, callback);
}
else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Android)
{
    Lib_Android.Helper helper = new Lib_Android.Helper();
    helper.launchScreen(parameters, callback);
}
```

**Error**

> You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it.

**Note: As a part of business requirement, I need to use only the .dll in the iOS and Android application**

Answer (score 0):

Please see the official article about code sharing options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/code-sharing.

If you want to use the same code with platform-specific conditions, you can create a shared project. Conditions will look like

```
#if __ANDROID__
...
#else
...
#endif
```

Comment: The disadvantage of using this approach is that the project needs to be a part of the application. But in my case, I want to share the only the .dll (assembly). This is what I read in the doc -----> "Unlike most other project types, a Shared Project has no 'output' assembly. During compilation, the files are treated as part of the referencing project and compiled into that assembly. If you wish to share your code as a assembly then Portable Class Libraries or .NET Standard are a better solution."